# parallel computing in octave

Tags: parallel-processing, octave

I found some sources online that indicate that there are tools for Octave that allow one to parallelize algorithms, but couldn't find any details or how to get and use them.  Any help/insight into this would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://octave.sourceforge.net/parallel/
Just install the package and the function reference may help.

Comment: On the link you sent it says: "For parallel execution on a single machine see e.g. function parcellfun (author: Jaroslav Hajek) in package general."

I'm not sure what that means...I'd like to be able to run a loop in Octave in parallel on a single machine.

Comment: Try this link now http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/